# SELECT COUNT(*) with an ORDER BY

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Will the following two queries be executed in the same way?

`SELECT COUNT(*) from person ORDER BY last_name;`

and

`SELECT COUNT(*) from person;`

Either way they should display the same results, so I was curious if the `ORDER BY` just gets ignored.

The reason I am asking is because I am displaying a paginated table where I will get 20 records at a time from the database and then firing a second query that counts the total number of records. I want to know if I should use the same criteria that the first query used, or if I should be removing all sorting from the criteria?

Comment: Have you checked the query plan first? I'm sure you have the analyzer around if you care about such small differences. It will tell you if sort occurs or not.

Comment: I would remove an ordering clause from any commutative aggregate functions (like COUNT or SUM) simply because it's unnecessary.

Comment: The results may differ in different versions of Oracle. Removing the ORDER BY from a query that only returns an aggregate is an optional optimisation.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Thanks. For me the results turned out to be different when I used explain plan. I am now curious why it wouldn't always be optimized out?

Comment: No optimisation is automatic - it requires code to implement. Oracle has coded thousands of optimisations so far, adding more optimisations in each version of the database - but there are probably many more thousands of potential optimisations they are yet to code for, waiting for someone to think of them.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp could you elaborate on why it is not automatic in this case? To me, the two statements are semantically equal (in case of counting things, the order of these things does not matter), therefore Oracle could simply pick any of the indexes that enable counting of all rows in the most efficient way (eg if there is a primary key column with an efficient index type)

Comment: Oracle (the database) won't do something unless someone at Oracle (the vendor) writes code to do it. It's not magic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the execution plan, the two queries are different.  For example, the query:

```
select count(*) from USER
```

Will give me:

```
INDEX (FAST FULL SCAN)  3.0 3   453812  3457        1   TPMDBO  USER_PK FAST FULL SCAN  INDEX (UNIQUE)  ANALYZED
```

As you can see, we hit USER_PK which is the primary key of that table.

If I sort by a non-indexed column:

```
select count(*) from USER ORDER BY FIRSTNAME --No Index on FIRSTNAME
```

I'll get:

```
TABLE ACCESS (FULL) 19.0    19  1124488 3457    24199   1   TPMDBO  USER    FULL    TABLE   ANALYZED    1
```

Meaning we did a full table scan (MUCH higher node cost)

If I sort by the primary key (which is already index,) Oracle is smart enough to use the index to do that sort:

```
INDEX (FAST FULL SCAN)  3.0 3   453812  3457    13828   1   TPMDBO  USER_PK FAST FULL SCAN  INDEX (UNIQUE)  ANALYZED
```

Which looks very similar to the first execution plan.

So, the answer to your question is absolutely not - they are not the same.  However, ordering by an index that Oracle is already seeking anyway will probably result in the same query plan.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Unless last name is the primary key and you are already ordered by that.

Comment: I don't think the answer is obvious.  Oracle will often throw out useless steps, especially unnecessary sorting.  I initially expected the two queries to run the same way.

Comment: It may not be obvious to you but seems like that's what the correct answer is as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle query optimizer actually does perform a sort (I verified this looking at the explain plan) for the first version, but since both queries only return one row, the performance difference will be very small.

**EDIT:**

Mike's answer is correct. The performance difference can possibly be significant.

Comment: `SORT ORDER BY` is sorting, `SORT AGGREGATE` is not really sorting.  And although the queries return the same number of rows the performance difference could still be huge.